# Cocos2d:Do I have to many Classes, should I condense?

Tags: c++, class, cocos2d-x

Cocos2d-X 2.1.4

Working in a game and I am finding that I keep creating classes for just a single purpose and I feel like I might be making a mistake

I have a `GameLayerObject()` class as a singleton.

I then have a `GameLayer()` class, extends `CCLayerMultiplex`.

`GameLayer` class houses creation of my `FieldLayer` class and my `TablesLayer` classes which extend `CCLayer`.

I could technically create all of these in the construction of `GameLayerObject()` having `GameLayer`, `FieldLayer` and 'TablesLayer` as member variables.

Instead of `GameLayerObject()` creating `GameLayer` which creates `FieldLayer` and `TablesLayer`

Someone else also recommended that all of this each be a singleton since there is only ever needing to be one instance of each class. I am aware of the pros and cons brought up about singletons.

Can anyone help me understand how to organize classes and a methodology when you have multiple classes that need to all work together and depend upon each other?

Comment: Read a good book or two on oop design as well as Code Complete, and practice, practice, practice. An abundance of practice and reflection on previous code will teach you the most. This is the art of programming, there's no simple answer, no silver bullet tried and true formula that works best under all circumstances.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D can you provide your insight on the 2 ways I laid out?

Comment: No because it's too theoretical and I don't have all the context. I can tell you that making any node class a singleton is a bad idea, this can mess with cocos' mem management.